# There is a delay between notification sound and notification banner for mail app in High Sierra. How can I fix this?

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, high-sierra

Whenever I receive a notification from mail, I hear the notification sound but the banner shows up 3-5 seconds later. There is a delay between the notification sound and notification banner. This problem is only specific to mail app. How can I fix it? I have tried restarting and some other standard/quick fixes but nothing helped. This issue also came up after I updated to High Sierra. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I've also been seeing this since upgrading to High Sierra. It's happening on three computers, even after a clean install.

Comment: I've tried updating to the latest version, quitting and restarting the app and the computer and everything else I could possibly imagine, but nothing seems to work. It seems to that the bug is in the source code of the app rather than something with the system. I also posted this problem on a few other platforms but didn't receive a reply yet!

Comment: I'm having this problem on Mojave (10.14.6) even after reinstalling the OS

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue on a 2017 27" iMac.
Spoke to Apple support....(I have APPLE CARE)

They had me do 3 things:

1. Upgrade to the latest version of macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 (That alone did not fix it).
2. [Reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201295) (for my desktop machine, they had me shut down and unplug the machine for 15 seconds instead).
3. [Reset the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204063).

Comment: that is really weird. i would have thought this was a software bug that could be easily fixed but I actually got another mail client so I don't apple mail anymore.

Comment: that being would following these steps be useful just as a regular maintenance of the machine? because there are times when I get some random bugs here and there which bog my mind

Comment: Resetting NVRAM did the job for me!

Comment: Could someone actually explain why resetting NVRAM fixes this problem? After all, Mail is, I suppose, a normal application that can issue notifications. What NVRAM has to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

I was plagued with this issue too since upgrading to High Sierra, here's how I fixed it:

- Close the Mail app;
- Go to  Settings - Notifications - Mail;
- Select "None" for the alert type;
- Untick ALL of the other options for Mail notifications;
- Close Settings;
- Open Mail and hit send and receive;
- Close Mail;
- Go back to the notification settings for Mail and restore the previous settings (or whatever you want to use in there);

These steps got me rid of the annoying 5 second delay between the notification sound and the popup showing up, hope it works for you guys as well.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution. personally, it was pretty annoying so I just gave up on mail, and downloaded the official outlook app, which works well enough that I can't be bothered to even open mail again.

Comment: Right, I got to say the issue was back a couple of days later, so this workaround didn't fully fix the problem.

Comment: very strange. because I have a few friends who use macbooks, and they didn't seem to have this issue so I am wondering what could be the cause. hopefully Apple takes notice 

Answer (score 3):

Simply resetting the NVRam solved the problem for me.  (I'd add this as a comment to Michael's answer, but I lack the rep.)